# SAPUI5 Text control unable to display Phone num as link in Chrome but does in Edge

Tags: html, google-chrome, sapui5

When I pass a phone number from backend in brackets like (+XX YYYYYYYY) in between a string, as a Text field using a sap.m.Text control, it doesn't show the clickable link in Chrome. But it does show the phone num as a clickable link in Edge.

Below is my Index meta and bootstrap:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatiable" content="IE=edge" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Overview</title>
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="./resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.core"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-preload="async"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"test.app": "."}'>
    </script>
```

Inside the view:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:customData="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
<VBox>
                            <Text class="padding" text="{Desc}"
                                style="padding-top:0.5rem;" />
                        </VBox>
```

the above binding field "Desc" contains the string with phone num.

Is there any thing special I need to mention for it to work in Chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

A text will not be clickable in either chrome or edge.

If you need a clickable icon when you hover the text , Use the CSS Property **Cursor:pointer** or you can use link control available in sapui5 controls.

you can add your css in the class you given.suggest you to add your css in css  file and avoid using inline css

Comment: This does not seem to accurately reflect OP's experience of being able to click on the text in Edge.

Comment: Hi,
Edge is able to recognise the telephone number and make it clickable automatically and hence I am wondering why isnt the same happening in Chrome.
This is a Text field containing the phone number.

Comment: In that case ,are you doing something on the click event of the text ? May be the version of IE you use shows the text as clickable .may be a browser issue . Why do you want a text field to be clickable ?? If you want it to be clickable you can use link control . A screenshot of your issue would help me to answer you better

Comment: Hi, I dont want the whole text to be clickable, but a telephone number inside the text to be clickable. So part of the text which contains the number should be clickable.Not the whole text.